# How to wire DC kilovolt meter?

Tags: high-voltage

I recently picked up a small DC analog kilovolt meter. The scale went up to roughly 25kv.

I have some microwave oven transformers I would like to test the voltage.

I hooked a microwave diode in series with the kilovolt meter, as an attempt to measure the voltage.

All of the lights dimmed, and the meter essentially acted as a dead short. I thought "I couldn't have burned out a 25kv meter with roughly 2kv" but some more testing provided the same results.

Is there something wrong with the setup? I don't have any info on the meter at the moment other than its a small 1.5 inch diameter analog meter that reads "DC kilovolts" and has a connection on the back for + and -. Yes, I am sure the diode was pointing
The right way.

The meter is very similar to [this one on eBay](http://ebay.com/itm/231178727180?nav=SEARCH).
Simpson 50280 MOD 27 panel meter 3" 0-500 2 kV

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please don't use eBay links as reference.  Such links perish quickly and certainly, because eBay auctions expire.  You can easily include a couple of images (front and back of the meter) and the 1-line description into your post.

Comment: If you look at the Ebay link, you would see that the meter is described as FS=500 uA.  This means that the meter itself is just a 500 uA meter and requires a multiplier resistor to be able to measure 2 kV. Ignoring the meter resistance, the value of the multiplier is 2kV/500 uA or 4 megohms. That resistor would also have to be able to handle the full 2 kV as well as the connecting wires.  All in all, a lot of careful component selection and layout is needed to make this meter in a kilovolt capable voltmeter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

High-voltage off-the-shelf panel meters almost universally require external multiplier resistor(s), so you've no doubt destroyed the meter and, most likely, the diode as well by not including the required resistance in your setup.

To find out, check the diode's front-to-back resistance, and the meter's continuity using an ohmmeter. Start with the highest resistance range and work downward, and if the meter's not totally ruined you should see its pointer deflect at some point.

Comment: Yes, just to emphasize:  With panel meters the scale printed on the meter doesn't necessarily mean that the meter can directly support that range of voltage/current/whatever at its terminals.  Often they are designed to read correctly in conjunction with external components like specific resistors or shunts.  Obviously the datasheet is key here.

Comment: Do you mean divider resistors so I can divide the voltage to an Ok range?

Comment: skyler: No, I meant "multiplier". http://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/Multiplier

Answer (score -1):

Voltage measurements are done in *parallel* with the tested component. That means that you connect the one lead to one wire on the transformer, and one lead to the other. It sounds like you connected one lead to the transformer, and the other to either power or ground.

As a very important sidenote, transformers only work with AC current. I have absolutely no idea how you intend to use this meter.

Comment: When measuring the output voltage of an unloaded source, parallel and series are equivalent.

Comment: Depends on if he's measuring the primary or secondary side. If he intends to measure the secondary, then the issue shouldn't have occurred (unless the meter has a short), so it sounds like he's measuring the primary. On the secondary side, though, what you said is true.

Comment: He also never said it was unloaded. I understood the question that way, but it might be connected to something.